# How to set default NetBeans project settings?

Tags: c++, netbeans

I use NetBeans to develop c++. The default setting is to use an older c++ standard. I want to use c++11 for all my projects, but I can not find a way to set the default. Currently, what I have to do every time I create a project, is go File -> Project Properties -> C++ Compiler -> C++ Standard -> C++11. It gets very cumbersome to do this every single time I create a project, and I am trying to set the default C++ standard that will automatically be applied whenever I create a new project. I have been searching around for a few days, and I haven't found any help online. Could anyone help me out? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing your concerns on NetBeans 8.2:

- **C++11** can be set during project creation. Setting it on the **Properties** screen is unnecessary.
- After selecting **C++11** in the project wizard it becomes the default selection until it is changed.

You specify **C++11** using the wizard when creating your C++ project:

- **File > New Project...**
- Select **Categories: C/C++** then **Projects: C/C++ Application**
- Click **Next >**
- On the **Project Name and Location** screen select **C++11** from the drop list to the right of **Create Main File**. This is only necessary the first time you create a C++ project. After that it will default to **C++11**.

[image: cppC++11]

After completing the wizard, **Properties > Build > C++ Compiler > C++ Standard** shows that the value is already set to **C++11**.

Am I completely misunderstanding your concern? Or are you possibly using an older version of NetBeans without that drop list shown in the screen shot above?

Comment: I completely missed that!